# Change data of second combo box,onchange of the first one

Tags: javascript, php

I am having 2 combo boxes.in the 1st one has state names I have data retrieved from the database,second one has to districts of that particular state.what I need is that on onchange in data in the first combobox.data in the second should also be changed.here is my code.

```
<select name="district" id="district" onchange="showcomplain()">
<?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM `rev_district_master`";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Selection query of District Master is Error".mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row[1];?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>
<?php
    }
?> 
This is my ajax file:

function stateComboChange(){

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
{
alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
return;
}else{          
var url="./ajax/list1.php";
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged1 ;
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null)  ;
}
}
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
{
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
    //Internet Explorer
    try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
return xmlHttp;
}

function stateChanged1() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
document.getElementById("stateCombo").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText; }
```

}

Comment: Do you want to code it yourself or somebody to code it for you?

Comment: use ajax on selection of first combo

Comment: Is there any tutorial for these type of code.i am new to php and ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Do it through ajax call on change of state

```
function changeCombo(){
                var statename=document.getElementByid('state_combo_box').value;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
                {
                    if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                       var data=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                for(var index= 0;index<data.length;index++)
                {
                    var combo=document.getElementById('district');
                    combo.options[combo.options.length] = new Option(districtname, value);

}
                    }

                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","some_php_file_which_echos_data.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send(statename);
        }


    }
```

Sorry i don't how you named your DOM elements but replace files and id names

Comment: thanks.
 
Is there any tutorial for these type of code.i am new to php and ajax

Comment: sorry for late reply,but very basic tutorials you can go for  [link](www.W3schools.com )

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data of the second combobox?... I don't see this code.

You can use AJAX request to database and change de data on callback.